# Problem using std::vector with a class/struct containing Eigen types defined in separate file

Tags: c++, vector, std, eigen

EDIT  >>conclusion, conflicting Eigen versions because of crappy local configuration? <<

I am trying to define a struct which contains an Eigen::Matrix.
When I use a std::vector and populate the array using some function some strange things occur.

EDIT >> full source code below <<

When I define everything in same file, like above no problem. Vector is populated and returns properly, calling size()accessing  the resultant vector is fine. (size() = 10).

When I define the types and function in  separate .h and .cpp files to the main and do the same thing, the returned data is shifted so that size() returns 12.

Looking at the matrix elements I can observe that the data shifts 1 element to the right for each object in the vector.

The only way I can get it to work when defined in a separate file is to declare the matrix as

```
Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 4, Eigen::DontAlign> tf
```

but I guess that is not good for efficiency later.
Any ideas what the problem is? I assume its due to aligning the matrix when allocating, but why is this a problem when compiling/linking from different source files?

Ubuntu 16.04
gcc 5.4.0
c++std 11
Eigen 3.2.1 (provided by GTSAM slam package)

EDIT->>>>

complete source code:

key_frames.h

```
#ifndef __KEY_FRAMES_H__
#define __KEY_FRAMES_H__

#include <Eigen/Dense>

struct test_t {
    EIGEN_MAKE_ALIGNED_OPERATOR_NEW
    Eigen::Matrix<float, 4, 4> tf;
    int key;
};

void load_test_v(std::vector<test_t,
             Eigen::aligned_allocator<test_t> > & test_vector);
#endif
```

key_frames.cc

```
#include <vector>

#include "key_frames.h"

void load_test_v(std::vector<test_t,
             Eigen::aligned_allocator<test_t> > & test_vector){

     for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     test_t tt;
     tt.tf = Eigen::Matrix4f::Random();
     tt.key = i;
     test_vector.push_back(tt);
    }
 }
```

opt_key_frames.cc

```
#include <iostream>

#include <gtsam/geometry/Pose2.h>

#include "key_frames.h"

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
   std::vector<test_t,
          Eigen::aligned_allocator<test_t> > test_vector;
   test_vector.clear();
   std::cout << "size of test vector " << test_vector.size() << "\n";
   load_test_v(test_vector);
   std::cout << "size of test vector " << test_vector.size() << "\n";
}
```

This is the minimum replicable source. To build I link to gtsam libraries.
Of interest, if I remove the

```
#include <gtsam/geometry/Pose2.h>
```

the code works (size() returns 10).
Also if I copy the exact code and make file to different directory it works .

out put from valgrid:

```
--14269-- REDIR: 0x5c0abb0 (libc.so.6:bcmp) redirected to 0x4a28770 (_vgnU_ifunc_wrapper)
--14269-- REDIR: 0x5cea430 (libc.so.6:__memcmp_sse4_1) redirected to 0x4c33780 (__memcmp_sse4_1)
size of test vector 0
--14269-- REDIR: 0x5c03600 (libc.so.6:posix_memalign) redirected to 0x4c2fd12 (posix_memalign)
size of test vector 12
==14269== 
==14269== HEAP SUMMARY:
==14269==     in use at exit: 72,736 bytes in 2 blocks
==14269==   total heap usage: 259 allocs, 257 frees, 98,174 bytes allocated
==14269== 
==14269== Searching for pointers to 2 not-freed blocks
==14269== Checked 2,634,840 bytes
==14269== 
==14269== LEAK SUMMARY:
==14269==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14269==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14269==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14269==    still reachable: 72,736 bytes in 2 blocks
==14269==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==14269== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
```

if remove the gtsam include:

```
--14359-- REDIR: 0x54613b0 (libc.so.6:__GI_mempcpy) redirected to    0x4c34a90 (__GI_mempcpy)
size of test vector 0
--14359-- REDIR: 0x5459600 (libc.so.6:posix_memalign) redirected to 0x4c2fd12 (posix_memalign)
--14359-- REDIR: 0x54564f0 (libc.so.6:free) redirected to 0x4c2ec69 (free)
size of test vector 10
==14359==
```

So something is changing there.

Conclusion: my setup is messed up.
I suspect including Eigen/Dense is targeting Eigen3.3 installed system wide. While GTSam uses Eigen 3.2 shipped with the package, and for whatever reason my local setup is getting them confused, while when I run the code in a different directory, only GTSam Eigen is getting used.

Anyway thanks for the help. Working through it, helped me understand.

Comment: This story is rater unlikely to be complete. Please post a [mcve]. This means two separate *buildable* (full, complete, no `#include` directives or other "small" parts omitted) sets of files which reproduce the problem.

Comment: If `test_vector.size()`  returns 12 and not 10, then you have a severe memory issue, likely out of bound  write. Run your program within `valgrind` to find the origin of the issue.

Comment: n.m: you are right, it looks like inclusion of gtsam headers is causing confusion of Eigen version - so I'll push forward with trying to configure properly,

Comment: ggael: I ran valgrind, results in original, thanks for the tip